# localstorage deletes the previous data, how can I add new data?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Where am I making a mistake? When I add a new data, it deletes the previous data and adds a new one. However, I want it to be like this; If there is an id, do not add it, otherwise new data will be added with the previous data.

```
let array_item = [];

$('#bookmark').click(function() {

    let id = $(this).data("id");
    // We place the data from data-id into the array item array.

    array_item.push(id);

    let parsed = JSON.stringify(array_item);
    localStorage.setItem('array_item', parsed);
    console.log(parsed);
})
```

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: When you add more ids to array_item array, is it not storing all of them in localStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the data in storage, add to it, and then save the result. If you don't need `array_item` outside the handler, that would look like this:

```
$('#bookmark').click(function(){
    let id = $(this).data("id");
    // We place the data from data-id into the array item array.
    const array_item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array_item") || "[]");
    array_item.push(id);
    localStorage.setItem("array_item", JSON.stringify(array_item));
});
```

If you do need it outside the handler, but the handler is the only place you add to it, that looks like this:

```
const array_item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array_item") || "[]");
$('#bookmark').click(function(){
    let id = $(this).data("id");
    // We place the data from data-id into the array item array.
    array_item.push(id);
    localStorage.setItem("array_item", JSON.stringify(array_item));
});
```

Or you could have a function that does it that you can call from multiple places:

```
const array_item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array_item") || "[]");
function addArrayItem(item) {
    array_item.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("array_item", JSON.stringify(array_item));
}
$('#bookmark').click(function(){
    let id = $(this).data("id");
    // We place the data from data-id into the array item array.
    addArrayitem(id);
});
```

Comment: Added data is not instantaneous. After the data is added, do I need to refresh the page to see it processing?

How can I make it work instantly?

Comment: @SiyahKlasör - It basically is instantaneous, what makes you say it isn't? `localStorage` operations are synchronous and very, very, very fast. When `setItem` returns, the storage has been updated.

Comment: When I output it with console.log, I saw that the data I added was not added instantly.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking from the wrong area. Fast data loading. Thank you for your support

Comment: I'm trying to print it out but it only prints the last data. Why could it be?array_item.forEach(function(item,index,array){
  const output = item.title;
  document.getElementById("mark").innerHTML = output;
 });

Comment: However, when I look at the console log, I see that all the added data are listed.

Comment: And lastly, what should I do when I want to delete data?

Comment: You're constantly overwriting the previous output with the next. Re deleting data: Look at the series of operations in the answer. They're: 1. Load the array from storage; 2. Modify the array; 3. Put the array in storage. It doesn't matter what kind of modifications you're doing at step 2 -- adding, removing, mapping, filtering...

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Don't deleted. $('#remove').click(function(){
  localStorage.removeItem('id');
 })

Comment: @SiyahKlasör - Why would it? You don't have anything stored under `'id'`. You have an array (as JSON) stored as `array_item`.

Comment: Is it possible to add an example to the answer? At least anyone who has a problem like me will learn this too.

Comment: @SiyahKlasör - Instead of `array_item.push(id)`, it's `array_item = array_item.filter(e => e !== id);` The rest is the same. [More here](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+remove+item+from+array).